# How to avoid AlertDialog Crash on Passing Context

Tags: java, android, dialog, android-alertdialog, android-theme

I have noticed a trend with the AlertDialog in Android. It inconsistently crashes complaining of the type of Context passed to the AlertBuilder constructor.

Is this a known issue and how can I completely avoid this from happening in production.

```
    AlertDialog.Builder alertBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getApplicationContext())
                                .setTitle("Title")
                                .setMessage("Your message that the user won't see cause this might just crash the app")
                                .setPositiveButton("Okay", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                                        dialogInterface.dismiss();
                                    }
                                });
                        alertBuilder.create().show();
```

```
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.
            at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.createSubDecor(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:843)
            at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.ensureSubDecor(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:806)
            at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:693)
            at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDialog.setContentView(AppCompatDialog.java:95)
            at androidx.appcompat.app.AlertController.installContent(AlertController.java:232)
            at androidx.appcompat.app.AlertDialog.onCreate(AlertDialog.java:279)
            at android.app.Dialog.dispatchOnCreate(Dialog.java:465)
            at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:333)
            at org.aplusscreators.com.views.onboarding.SubscriptionPlanActivity$4.onClick(SubscriptionPlanActivity.java:145)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6719)
            at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:6677)
            at android.view.View.access$3400(View.java:797)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:26475)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:226)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7212)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:576)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:956)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is here:

```
new AlertDialog.Builder(getApplicationContext())
```

You have to pass `Activity` as context instead of `getApplicationContext()`.
The `ApplicationContext` **has not** the app theme.

Comment: Just to confirm,  do you mean  ActivityName.this ?

Comment: @samuelowino yes

Comment: I can confirm this works, although you might need to add a ContextThemeWrapper, not sure if it is completely necessary; new AlertDialog.Builder( new ContextThemeWrapper(ActivityName.this,R.style.AppTheme);

Comment: @samuelowino in this case you don't need a `ContextThemeWrapper` since it inherits the theme used by the `Activity`.

Answer (score 1):

Set a theme for that activity either in the manifest or programmatically before onCreate in the class.
You can also set it globally for the entire app inside application tag of manifest.

```
<application
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
....
```

Comment: Do I have to do this for every activity, that sound very messy? Shouldn't the Activity inherit AppTheme as am extending AppCompatActivity

Comment: @samuelowino you can set in globally inside application tag of manifest

Comment: No @SABANTO I already had this in my manifest file, it crashed anyways